# How to select multiple records and change their value at once

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Here is my problem and I do not know where and how to start to search about this.

In a MS Access database users will have a list of records returned from a query. Let's say employees which are active (employed). This table has a related table let's say departments (related through departmentID in both table).

What I want to do is to make form (or something else which would do the same job), where user will select some records (probably with checkboxes associated with each record) and there will be a single combobox with department names. When user selects a department name, its departmentID should be saved into departmentID field of these records.

I have created a form with a query of active employees (form with multiple items). And put an extra field in Detail section with a checkbox. In Form footer I have a combobox with Department names and IDs (not shown to user), and a button to save values.

I have to now figure out, how to select all rows/records with a checked checkbox and update them. I am by the way familiar with VB and SQL.

I would appreciate any idea/knowledge on how to solve this.

Comment: How are you currently displaying your multiple employees?  With a continuous form, list box or a sub form?

Answer (score 0):

An extra field in the Detail section won't help you if you don't link it with a data field in the displayed table. If you can do that, then you have simply to make a VBA function to update all selected rows, and refresh the recordset.

If you cannot modify your table, you'll have to create a new table with just the key columns of your master table, and manage it via VBA. Better to use the first option if you can, it pollutes your schema, but in most cases that won't be a problem for an Access database.